# set /p empty answer crash even with quotations (very strange behavior) (batch on Windows)

Tags: batch-file

I found a very strange behavior of batch script on Windows. Why does the first example crashes but not the others when pressing enter without anything?

This will crash if you just press enter without anything.

```
@echo off 
set /p menuinput= 

if "%menuinput%"=="" (
    Echo just enter input
    pause
) else if "%menuinput:~2,2%"==":\" (
    echo A destination path has been input with quotations.
    pause
) else (
    echo anything else
    pause
)
exit
```

But this will not crash even if you just press enter without anything.

```
@echo off 
set /p menuinput= 

if "%menuinput%"=="" (
    Echo just enter input
    pause
) else (
    echo anything else
    pause
)
exit
```

Also this will not crash even if you just press enter without anything.

```
@echo off 
set menuinput=""
set /p menuinput= 

if "%menuinput%"=="" (
    Echo just enter input
    pause
) else if "%menuinput:~2,2%"==":\" (
    echo A destination path has been input with quotations.
    pause
) else (
    echo anything else
    pause
)
exit
```

Comment: When you enable and apply [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) such problems can be avoided: `if "!menuinput!"=="" (…) else …`; this even allows unbalanced quotes to be input. To check against empty input you could also use [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html): `set "menuinput=" & set /P menuinput="" || (echo Empty input)`. Finally, consider to use [`choice`](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) for menus…

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your third example is significant, so I've rolled it back.

The reason for the crash with the first example is that if `menuinput` is empty, then `else if "%menuinput:~2,2%"==":\" (` will yield a syntax error. The second succeeds because you are not attempting to find a substring of an empty string.

The third - well, actually, this `set`s `menuinput` to `""`. This is not an empty string. Note that `set /p` will leave the variable unaltered if you simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Batch parses the entire statement from `if` though to the very last closing parenthesis in the logical statement, so it finds a syntax error and barfs. Only if the statement is syntactically correct with the statement be executed (the same goes for a `for` statement, of course).

Had you used `set "menuinput="` before the `set /p` then `menuinput` would have been "set" to ***nothing***

Attempting to reliably parse a `set /p`-input value is fraught with problems.

So, to detect a just-<kbd>Enter</kbd>, set the variable to nothing, then execute the `set /p` and then use

```
if not defined menuinput goto noinput
```

Then attack the problem of the further analysis of the input-string.

Running a proper menu is often discussed - there are many items on SO - just use the `search` facility. (I'm mentioning this solely because of the variablename you used)

Also, you appear oto be using `pause` to try to catch the window before it closes. When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will often close if a syntax-error is found. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any error message will be displayed.